# Get user's current region android

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to get the user's current region. Typically country. I tried the below code... but It gives me always "in" although I changed the region from "India" to "United States" in settings.

```
public static String getUserCountry2(Context context) {
    try {
        final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        final String simCountry = tm.getSimCountryIso();
        if (simCountry != null && simCountry.length() == 2) { // SIM country code is available
            return simCountry.toLowerCase(Locale.US);
        } else if (tm.getPhoneType() != TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA) { // device is not 3G (would be unreliable)
            String networkCountry = tm.getNetworkCountryIso();
            if (networkCountry != null && networkCountry.length() == 2) { // network country code is available
                return networkCountry.toLowerCase(Locale.US);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

Settings from where I'm changing Region

[image: Settings Screen]

Comment: What do you mean by changing region in settings? Do you mean the play store region? AFAIK, there is no such setting in the settings app where you select your country. You're querying the region based on sim and network code, so you'll always get India as long as your sim is in an Indian network. The best way to get the region is to ask user for location permissions

Comment: @sonnet Let me update the question... I will add screenshots of from where I'm changing the region... Maybe that will clarify the question.

Comment: Changing the region from there will probably change your Locale. So if you change the region and log the Locale you can confirm it, but it has nothing to do with your sim and network settings. So, getting country code from sim/network would still give you IN

Comment: So, You mean I need to check Locale instead?@sonnet

Comment: @sonnet I tried checking Locale by...
`Locale defaultLocale = Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0);`
But I'm getting `en_US` although my region is "India". If I change region to "United States" still I'm getting "en_US".

Comment: There are just too many questions and things to consider. For example: do you want user's current country based on their location? What if they go to a different country to visit for two days? Do you want that country for two days during those two days or the country they always stay at? Depending on these, you can either ask the user to input their country and do your logic based on that. Or you can use a variety of approaches to get the correct current location: gps, pinging your server and determining by ip, network/sim, etc

Comment: @sonnet Okay. I get your point. Thanks!